# Syntax independent presentation of Homotopy Type Theory

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory, cartesian-closed-categories

By "syntax independent" I mean no explicit reference to variables. For example, Lambda Calculus is syntax dependent because the notions of "variable", "variable renaming", and "substing a term for a variable" are present right from the start, whereas the theory of Cartesian Closed Categories is less explicit about variables.

To give another example; thinking of an indexed family of types as $x:A \vdash B$ is syntax dependent, but thinking of it as a function $B: A \rightarrow \mathcal{U}$ is syntax independent, because this second form hides the variable $x$.

I am not giving a formal definition of syntax independence, but I hope it is clear what I mean.

Is there a presentation of Homotopy Type Theory that is syntax independent?

Comment: Perhaps you want the idea of an [$(\infty, 1)$-topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/elementary+%28infinity%2C1%29-topos)?

Comment: I do not know what an $(\infty, 1)$-topos is, do you recomend some introductory book?

Comment: There's a list of references at the bottom of the linked nlab page. I haven't read all of them, but I don't think you'll find anything that's _truly_ "introductory". They're necessarily complex objects. But intuitively, $(\infty,1)$-toposes and HoTT are linked in a way that's almost one-to-one analogous to the way Cartesian Closed Categories and $\lambda$-calculus are linked. Both give natural [categorical semantics](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/categorical+semantics) for a certain logic (HoTT or $\lambda$-calculus, respectively)

Comment: If you're asking about whether there is a structure that's related to HoTT in the same way that CCCs are related to STLC, then something like an $(\infty,1)$-topos is probably what you want.  However, I would not call it an $(\infty,1)$-topos any kind of "presentation of HoTT", nor would I call a CCC any kind of "presentation of lambda-calculus". HoTT and lambda-calculus are intrinsically syntactic objects; the corresponding categorical objects are related, but different.